# Laravel storing only the last element of the array in the DB table (foreach loop)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I uploaded multiple images on the database:

[image]
In the next step I'm trying to change the value of alt column based on dynamically created inputs located on the blade page:

[image]

But after I submit and entered values in HTML inputs, LARAVEL app stores only value  (example2) from last HTML input in both images(records) within the alt column.

[image]

**altPictures.blade.php**

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')

    @include('nav')

    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="center-align">Insert alt Text for uploaded images</h1>
        @if(count($errors) > 0)
            <div class="materialert warning" id="close-dialog">
                <i class="material-icons">warning</i>
                <span>
                    @foreach($deletePost ->all() as $error)
                        <ul>
                            <li>{{$error}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    @endforeach
                </span>
            </div>
        @endif

        {!! Form::open(['action' =>  ['HomepageController@altPicturesPost', $language->url], 'method' => 'POST', 'files' => true]) !!}

        @foreach($pictures as $picture)

            <img class="center-block img-responsive" src="/uploads/homepage_galery/{{ $picture->filename }}"/>

            <div class="form-group">
                {{Form::label('naslov', 'Type alt text of image')}}
                {{Form::text('alt['.$picture->id.']', '', ['id' => 'alt', 'class' => ($errors->has('naslov')) ? 'form-control is-invalid' : 'form-control',  'placeholder' => 'Type alt text of image '])}}
            </div>

            {!! Form::hidden('id['.$picture->id.']', $picture->id) !!}

        @endforeach

        {{Form::submit('Submit', ['class' => 'btn blog-button']) }}

        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div><!-- /container -->

@endsection
```

**HomeGaleryConroller**

```
public function altPictures($url)
{
    $languages = Language::where('url', '=', $url)->get();
    $language = Language::where('url', '=', $url)->first();
    if (count($language) == 0) {
        abort(404);
    }

    $languagesLists = Language::all();
    $languagesSelect = Language::pluck('title', 'id');
    $categories = Category::with('firstsubcategories')->get();
    $subcategories = SubCategory::All();
    $secondsubcategories = SecondSubCategory::All();
    $listings = CategoryListing::All();
    $navposts = Post::all();
    $navproducts = Product::all();
    $subListings = SubcategoryListing::All();
    $SecSubListings = SecSubcategoryListing::All();
    $pictures = HomeGalery::all();

    return view('homepageGalery/altPictures', ['languages' => $languages, 'language' => $language, 'languagesLists' => $languagesLists, 'categories' => $categories, 'listings' => $listings, 'subcategories' => $subcategories, 'secondsubcategories' => $secondsubcategories, 'adminpaneListings' => $adminpaneListings, 'navposts' => $navposts, 'navproducts' => $navproducts, 'adminpanelSublistings' => $adminpanelSublistings, 'adminpanelSecSublistings' => $adminpanelSecSublistings, 'subListings' => $subListings, 'SecSubListings' => $SecSubListings, 'languagesSelect' => $languagesSelect, 'pictures' => $pictures]);

}


public function altPicturesPost(Request $request, $url)
{
    foreach ($request->input('alt') as $alt) {
        $galeries = HomeGalery::wherein('id', $request->input('id'))->get();
        foreach ($galeries as $galery) {
            $galery->alt = $alt;
            $galery->save();
        }
    }

    return redirect()->route('adminpanel.homepage.galery', $url);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're actually loading all of the `HomeGalery` models on each loop.
`$request->input('id')` will return an array of all the ids in the page not the id that is specific to the `$picture`.

You would be better off just getting the key foreach 'alt' and then using `update()`:

```
public function altPicturesPost(Request $request, $url)
{
    foreach ($request->input('alt') as $galleryId => $alt) {
        HomeGalery::where('id', $galleryId)->update(compact('alt'));
    }

    return redirect()->route('adminpanel.homepage.galery', $url);
}
```

This way you can get rid of `{!! Form::hidden('id['.$picture->id.']', $picture->id) !!}` in your blade file  as well.